# Compare 2nd and 3rd field of CSV file for each row and if matches, do addition of 1st field in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, csv, for-loop

new to bash script and wanted to compare rows in input.csv file
if 2nd and 3rd field matches then
do addition of 1st field in output.csv

input.csv

```
Count, Number, Name  
1, 1111, abc  
4, 2222, zyx  
5, 1111, abc  
200, 3333, xyz  
2, 1111, xyz  
4, 3333, xyz  
2, 1111, abc
```

output.csv

```
Count, Number, Name
8, 1111, abc  
4, 2222, zyx  
204, 3333, xyz  
2, 1111, xyz
```

I tried with awk command and while loop

```
while IFS="," read -r   
do  
    awk  
done
```

Comment: "If 2nd and 3rd field matches" - matches to what? Are the same?

Comment: if 2nd and 3rd filed of a row matches with another row, then do addition of 1st field for those row.  
E.g. Count, Number, Name    
1, 1111, abc
5, 1111, abc
2, 1111, abc 
then output.csv will be
8, 1111, abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script does the job:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Save the first line of the output file without spaces
cat input.csv | head -1 | tr -d ' ' > output.csv

# $ cat output.csv
# Count,Number,Name

# Find the patterns of the processing by filtering the 2nd 
# and the 3rd columns of the input file
patterns="$(cat input.csv |
            tail -n +2 |
            sort -k 2 |
            cut -d , -f 2,3 |
            uniq |
            tr -d ' ')"

# $ echo "$patterns"
# 1111,abc
# 1111,xyz
# 2222,zyx
# 3333,xyz

# Do the maths and save the lines into the output file
for k in ${patterns}
do
    cat input.csv |
    tr -d ' ' |
    grep $k |
    awk -F, 'BEGIN{c=0}
                {c=c+$1}
            END{ printf("%s,%s,%s\n", c, $2, $3)}' >> output.csv
done

# $ cat output.csv
# Count,Number,Name
# 8,1111,abc
# 2,1111,xyz
# 4,2222,zyx
# 204,3333,xyz

# End finally ensure that output file has 
# the same format with the input file
sed -i "s/,/, /g" output.csv

# $ cat output.csv
# Count, Number, Name
# 8, 1111, abc
# 2, 1111, xyz
# 4, 2222, zyx
# 204, 3333, xyz
```

By breaking down the first iteration of the for loop, we have:

```
$ k="1111,abc"

$ cat input.csv
Count, Number, Name
1, 1111, abc
4, 2222, zyx
5, 1111, abc
200, 3333, xyz
2, 1111, xyz
4, 3333, xyz
2, 1111, abc

$ cat input.csv | tr -d ' '
Count,Number,Name
1,1111,abc
4,2222,zyx
5,1111,abc
200,3333,xyz
2,1111,xyz
4,3333,xyz
2,1111,abc

$ cat input.csv | tr -d ' ' | grep $k
1,1111,abc
5,1111,abc
2,1111,abc

$ cat input.csv | tr -d ' ' | grep $k | awk -F, 'BEGIN{c=0}{c=c+$1}END{ printf("%s,%s,%s\n", c, $2, $3)}'
8,1111,abc
```

Answer (score 1):

As most of "Unix toolbox" commands are primarily targeted to datasets, where lines are independent records, shell solution might be a bit more complex.

For starters I would suggest to split the work into a few parts.

1. Save a heading to a temporary file of a variable (it's just a heading, not a relevant record, but we will need it for producing the output file), e. g. the beginning of the output file.
2. Sort the rest of input file based on 2nd and 3rd field.
3. The most tricky part would be to add numbers, not only to count same lines, but when sorted it's kind of easy in awk or another language (previous record would be in a variable, after comparison added or printed out as a result via >> to an existing file, see 1.).

Why just a few advises and not a full code? We provide free answers not a free coding service, here :-)

Comment: i have sorted the rows numerically: awk 'NR>1' input.csv | sort -n

Comment: how to perform step 3?

Comment: First things first. Is simple `sort -n` what did you want? I guess, you need the sort based on 2nd and 3rd field taking the `,` delimiter (field separator in `sort` terms) into account too.

Answer (score -1):

1 - insert  into a db

2 - execute relevant query

3 - output result in file